# Style CSS with Javascript so it doesn't 'jump' with multi-page sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made some code (tool? framework? Not sure what to call it) that is intended to make it possible to style CSS with Javascript but not jump when reloading or changing pages (so for use in traditional multi-page sites... not sure the conventional term for that). I'm no web expert so am unsure if it's worth developing this further or if there's better solutions to what I'm trying to solve (more than likely).

The basic structure is

A. Under certain client-side conditions (e.g. browser resolution, but could be anything, like a certain user using the site), CSS is generated by client-side JS, written to a file on the server under the appropriate heading relative to scenario (e.g., 1024x768.css, 102400x76800.css).

B. The server code checks (via cookies) if client-side condition is met, checks if css file pertaining to condition exists, uses it, otherwise generates it (A.)

**Potential uses**

1. You inherit a legacy site or clients insist on a certain template (Wordpress theme), with predetermined HTML structure, such that it's difficult to achieve a custom look just modifying the CSS. It might be much quicker to make calculations and adjustments with Javascript than refactor the HTML or figure out the solution in CSS (time permitting the ideal solutions, arguably). On the other hand, you don't want the style to jump every time you load the page since that looks tacky.

*Edit: example of the above*

> As noted below in the comments, I can't think of a great example off the top of the ol' noggin. Right now my test is modifying a navigation menu of the type `<div class="menu"><ul><li><a>Section 1</a></li><li><a>Section n</a></li></ul></div>` such that the `<a>`'s have just enough padding on both sides that the menu `<div>` fully fills up the width of the browser.
>
> I imagine there's a conventional solution to this, so if you're feeling in the mood, please let me know.

2. You want particularly complicated sizing, positioning based on complex calculations (dependent on screen size, or not), but, again don't want things jumping around.

*Edit: example of the above*

> Positioning elements in a spiral pattern (say [this kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral)) with diminishing size. This seems to be nontrivial in CSS, perhaps done by calculating the positions beforehand and placing with absolute positioning. But then there's the problem of having everything scale depending on screen resolution.
>
> Alternately Javascript could calculate positions and sizes dynamically. Of course writing the method to correspond to the mathematical spiral function would be a challenge (though an interesting one).
>
> There could be other solutions like using .svg, but if written generically it would be possible to position according to other mathematical functions (e.g., sine wave), or complex ratios (golden mean) fairly easily.

3. You want a site where the user can customize the look (reposition or even resize elements) and you want the customization to automatically get remembered and generated in the server-side code (perhaps even without a login). I'm sure this is facilitated by many frameworks, but this kind of divests the process from a specific framework.

I was wondering if other folks had thoughts on whether:

A. There's a better solution to all this I've missed.

B. The system I described of pushing CSS from JS to be written on server sounds sound, or if the same thing could be achieved another way entirely client-side.

C. And I guess since it's not a specific technical question whether this is the right place to ask this question, and if not, where I should.

Like I said, I'm no expert, so would greatly appreciate any feedback or other things that might help me to learn.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use JavaScript to build multiple CSS files and handle which one is loaded? Why not just use media queries to control how the site looks at different sizes?

Comment: Yeah, agreed with Obsidian on that. Sounds like a horrid way of mimicking css media queries. Not sure what you mean by jump when loading pages. If you mean how the site can appear to shift due to a scrollbar, that's jut the way web browsers work. Some do that, some don't. You can get past it but it's probably not worth your time

Comment: @ObsidianAge Well this would be for scenarios where you have a set HTML structure that needs to be positioned or sized based on calculations that would have to be manually inserted into each possible responsive css. I'm no advanced CSS user and I imagine there'll a CSS work-around for practically any situation, but some solutions are more complex / hacky than others, and sometimes it'd be a lot quicker to place or size elements exactly how you need them with JS, which is where this concept comes into play. 

But I will try to think of a decent example to try to illustrate the use.

Comment: @KaiQing The 'jump' I'm talking about is the split second from DOM/CSS loading to Javascript executing (modifying DOM / CSS). From my understanding scripts always come after CSS--correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where it would actually be **easier** to style elements with JavaScript rather than CSS. WIth CSS you have things like percentage values, `em` and `rem` units... Don't forget you can also do **calculations** in CSS, like `height: calc(100vh - 40px);` to offset footers and the like :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge True true. The fact I'm having to think up valid scenarios perhaps indicates its limited usefulness. I'm slightly reticent / embarrassed to post what I'm actually testing it with right now since I imagine there are obvious solutions, such as padding elements in a <ul> navigation menu to fully fit the screen.

Comment: Go ahead and post what you've got so far -- even if there **are** obvious solutions, this site is designed to help find them, and we're more than happy to help :) Padding in a `<ul>` certainly sounds like a job for CSS though ;)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I edited my original post with some (I think) decent uses. Perhaps valid, or not. But anyhow, I greatly appreciate the replies.